Get port number of MQ Queue Manager using C#
I am writing an application in C# to read a message from a IBM WebSphere MQ queue, process the message and write a response to a different queue manager/queue. The incoming message contains properties defining the queue manager and queue name to use. This application is deployed in several different environments where the configuration of the queues may not be identical. e.g. On server A the queue manager may be listening on port 1415 but on another it is listening on port 1416 queue so when I create the QueueManager object I have to use the correct port number.
Putting the port number to use in a configuration file is messy as there are potentially many servers where the application is installed and the queue manager/queue name configuration may be different on each server.
Ideally what I want to do is something like
var MyManager = new MQQueueManager("ManagerName");
var PortNumber = MyManager.PortNo;

So I can write something like
var Properties = new Hashtable
{
    { MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, ManagerConfiguration.Host },
    { MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, ManagerConfiguration.Channel},
    { MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, GetPort("ManagerName" },
    { MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED }
};

I have looked at all the properties of a MQ Queue Manager in .Net but there does not seem to be anything that will do this. Is this possible? i.e Get the port number the queue manager is listening on given its name?
Thanks

I am confused with description here. If you are, from the message, getting queue manager and queue name where a response needs to be sent, then is it not possible to get connection parameters as well? Another curious point - how and where are you getting user ID and password to connect to the queue manager?
I would probably do it this way:

Keep the connection information for all the queue managers your application connects to in a configuration file.
During application runtime load that information into a hash table with queue manager name as the key.
When I get a message, I will look up the hash table using the queue manager name from the received message to determine connection parameters.

Hope this helps

Thanks for the quick response. The issue I have is that the incoming MQ Message contains the name of the MQ Manager to use and the MQ Queue to use, but as far as I can tell it does not contain the port number to use. I need the port number as the manager is not listening on the default part. So , what I need to do is given the queue manager name get the port number it is listening on. I can't put this in a configuration file as it may vary from server to server and there are many servers where this is running plus the queue manager/queue I need to reply to may vary from server to server.

Did you review the response from @Mark Taylor below? Are you doing request/reply type messaging?

Yes the message pattern is Request/Reply - I will look at the responses raised.

Then Marks response will do the job for you.

I THINK that this is talking about using the ReplyToQ/ReplyToQMgr (or ReplyTo Destination) fields from the inbound message, though it's not at all clear from the question which seems very confusing.
Assuming that's the case, you do not need to connect to the other queue manager. You just use those fields when putting the reply message to your local queue manager you are already connected to. It's the responsibility of the local administrator to have appropriate configuration - xmitq, channel etc - to resolve the route back to the originating queue manager.
Something like:
void replyToMessage(ITextMessage textMessage, ISession sessionWMQ)
{
  IDestination replyDestination = textMessage.JMSReplyTo;
  if (replyDestination != null)
  {
   ITextMessage replyMessage = sessionWMQ.CreateTextMessage();
   IMessageProducer producer = sessionWMQ.CreateProducer(replyDestination);
   ...

There is no other situation where MQ inherently passes information about other queues or queue managers; if it's coming from data contained in the message body, then you need to agree the contents with the creator of the original message.

Hi Mark - sorry for the confusion but in essence all I want to but resorting to a configuration file. e.g I want to writing something like
var PortNo = GetPortNo("QueueManagerName")

I know the manager name I just want to query the local WebSphere environment to get the associated port number(s) the manager is listening on.
